# Having trouble remembering a title about female assassin with nano suit or some sort of armor

Tags: story-identification

This is a book that I read in the last 5 or 6 years. I don't remember much of the plot, but I do remember that she finds the suit in some sort of wreckage. Then it's a blank until she's outside of a church, I think it was and nails some guy in the head, I think he was some government official, with the rifle she has but then the guy wakes up back in his ship in the body of a backup clone. It's some sort of space story I know that but beyond that, I don't remember much. I think I remember that the government was a very corrupt system and that she lost a family member to them, so she was on a quest to overthrow them.

Comment: Hello Loki, God of Mischief. If you remember any additional details, such as when you read this book, you can [edit] your question to add that. Also, please take a look at [this handy guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561) to see if anything jogs your memory.

Comment: I've voted to undelete your answer. It's perfectly valid to answer your own question. Ideally, of course, you'll want to provide additional details that will help other people find the book.

Comment: No, I deleted the answer because I was unsure if I was right so I wanted to read it again a little to be 100% sure before I accidentally lead people astray. And now that I have I am sure it is it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I remember the book's name. I found it on my Kindle account. For those that are wondering the book is R.P. Bird's *[Essa: In the Realm of the Gods](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CHAPSKS)*:

[image: Front cover of Essa: In the Realm of the Gods]

> Essa should be dead. But despite the god Lukshi's efforts, she is still alive. The gods enslaved humanity in the distant past. Essa lives on a planet several thousand light-years from Earth, except no one knows about Earth anymore. The study of history has been banned by the gods. Essa's father was killed in a heretic bombing. Essa's mother was worked to death on the orders of Lukshi, their planet's god. Not that the god knew she existed, for the entire population of the planet is being worked to death, except for the elites. The priests never seem to suffer. Essa was ordered to the temple brothel for her family's debts. She ran away instead. Abused, hunted, she found a device from ancient times, from when humanity stood against the gods. A suit of flexarmor had been kept safe inside its stasis container, waiting for someone to put it on. Intelligent, self-aware, constructed with the same technology that enables the gods, it has bound itself to Essa. With it as her companion, she will seek vengeance upon the gods and their servants. Only one group stands in her way, the premiere warriors of the era, the ones the gods themselves turn to when violent problems need a solution: the Hana. Their name means "spear point" in one of the ancient languages, not that anyone other than the Hana would know that. They have served as mercenaries to the gods for two thousand years. They are very good at what they do. The rage in Essa's heart will be answered with the cool professionalism of the Hana. By their battles, nothing on Essa's world will ever be the same again.

It's the third book in the "In the Realm of the Gods" series.